# Keyboard works on start up, but stops functioning as soon as the bios load

Tags: boot, keyboard, bios

I have quite an unusual problem. My keyboard works fine on the OS and during start up, so I can easily hit Del to enter bios or F8 to choose disk. In either those screens, however, the keyboard (and mouse, because my bios support that) suddenly stops working, even the leds (if on) shut down, and I can't do anything. Any ideas? My BIOS is Gigabyte UEFI DualBios. This problem started out of nowhere, as it worked fined last time I entered...

My question is indeed a duplicate of [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/674284/keyboard-no-longer-works-when-entering-bios), but the answers there don't quite help me because I don't have a PS/2 keyboard, or any other, for that matters. The thing is, it worked before, so I don't think it is an incompatibly with the keyboard or USB port. And I googled a lot before asking, but most posts out there are from people who can't use the keyboard on start up and bios, and not only on bios, so that is why I asked here. I'll try I different keyboard as soon as I get my hands on one, but I was hopping that someone could shed a light in the meanwhile.

And yes, it doesn't work only on the bios and bios boot selection screen.

Comment: Just to be clear: Your keyboard works fine normally, but it *only* doesn't work in a) the BIOS setup screen and b) the BIOS (not windows) boot device menu. Correct?

Comment: There are [*a lot* of discussions](https://www.google.com/search?q=keyboard%20doesn%27t%20work%20in%20bios) about this on the internet. Do any of those solutions work for you? Have you tried using a different keyboard? Also try other USB slots.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Keyboard no longer works when entering BIOS](http://superuser.com/questions/674284/keyboard-no-longer-works-when-entering-bios) (<- via comments, OP mentioned solution was to use a different USB port)

Comment: "... I don't think it is an incompatibly with the ... USB port." - But, have you tried the other USB ports? All of them?

Comment: @JasonC Sadly, I did...

Comment: So much for the easy fix. Since it suddenly stopped working with no configuration changes, it smells of a hardware failure. I'd try a new USB keyboard as the next step (and try it in all the USB ports if it doesn't work in one of them), and also try your keyboard in another computer. This will help narrow down if the issue is with the keyboard or with the computer.

Comment: Try taking the battery out of your motherboard for a few minutes with the mains disconnected. Your BIOS will be reset. Try your mouse and keyboard again.

Comment: Thanks, @BigChris, that did the trick! I removed the battery and now it works. Sorry to bother with such a specific problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you disconnect the BIOS/CMOS battery and the mains supply for a few minutes this will cause the BIOS to forget most of its settings and can often resolve many issues with mouse/keyboard not working in BIOS or boot device/priority problems.